# Why __consumer_offsets topic in kafka is not spreading to all the brokers?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a **3 zk** nodes cluster. And **7 kafka broker** nodes.

So when I create any topic then I can set replica factor and no of partitions using command line arguements.

And these partitions are spread to all the 7 brokers.But there is one topic i.e. `__consumer_offsets`,it is created automatically and  it is spreading to only 1 broker(id=0) with 1 replication.

I am aware that I could change the default no of replication factor in config file.

But, this topic is replicated to only one broker. So what is the parameter which could be changed to replicate the partitions to all the brokers.

Answer (score 10):

It sounds really strange to me. I deployed a 3 Kafka brokers cluster and my `__consumer_offsets` topic has 50 partitions (the default) split across the 3 brokers and having 3 (the default) as replicas.
What you are describing could happen when you start with a single Kafka broker, create consumers for reading topics so that the `__consumer_offsets` is automatically created and it will be just on the broker 0 (the only one). After that, you add new Kafka brokers: without doing anything the `__consumer_offsets` will still stay on broker 0; you need to use Kafka a manual partition reassignment for doing that as mentioned above.

Comment: "What you are describing could happen when you start with a single Kafka broker, create consumers for reading topics so that the __consumer_offsets is automatically created and it will be just on the broker 0 (the only one)"
Yes you are right...Our spark application was consuming data continously from kafka brokers. And I was not aware of that.
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: It was a pleasure ;)

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use Kafka partition reassignment. This is unfortunately a semi manual process currently:
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_cluster_expansion

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the "`offsets.topic.replication.factor`" to the desired number of replicas in the broker config.

> The replication factor for the offsets topic (set higher to ensure
> availability). To ensure that the effective replication factor of the
> offsets topic is the configured value, the number of alive brokers has
> to be at least the replication factor at the time of the first request
> for the offsets topic. If not, either the offsets topic creation will
> fail or it will get a replication factor of min(alive brokers,
> configured replication factor)
>
> Default: 3
> Importance: High

Reference  -
[http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs](https://kafka.apache.org/0102/documentation.html#brokerconfigs)

Comment: Yes, It will set replication factor. But __consumer_offset is still spreading only on one broker. So how Can i spread this topic on multiple brokers?